# Labeling Z3 scopes and popping back to a specific one

Tags: scope, label, z3

Is it possible to label Z3 scopes (SMTLib2 syntax) and to then pop back to a specific one? For example:

```
(push foo)
  ; ...
(push)
  ; ...
(pop foo) ; pops two scopes
```

I know that I can pop two scopes with `(pop 2)`, but in my scenario this means that I have to keep track of the number of yet unclosed scopes opened in between a push-pop pair that must match, i.e. that must restore the Z3 context as it existed before `(push foo)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Z3 does not have support for named scopes.